# C#, How to make and call functions

Tags: c#, function

I would like to start with seperating each if statement into seperate functions and then make sure that the menu is looped until a valid input has been made.

Could someone give me some good suggestions on how to solve this problem?

I also have an compiler-time error on the following line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < integer_array.length; i++)
```

Which I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is my complete code

```
int option;

Console.WriteLine("                                     ---  Random Number Generator  --- ");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("                                  Entre a number to Navigate");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("1).Run  Random Number Generator");
Console.WriteLine("2).Open Help Menu");
Console.WriteLine("3).Generate random numbers from a specific range. ");
Console.WriteLine("4).Exit ");

option= Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()); // Input by user which if statment to run 

if (option == 1)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("                                     ---  Random Number Generator  --- ");

    Random rand_number = new Random(); // creates a randon number

    HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();

    while (numbers.Count < 6)
    {
        int new_number = rand_number.Next(1, 50);

        if (!numbers.Contains(new_number))
            numbers.Add(new_number);
    } // creates 6 ramdon numbers between 1 and 50 and removes duplicate  

    int[] integer_array = numbers.ToArray(); // puts number in array 
    Array.Sort(integer_array); // sorts the array in assending order.


    Console.WriteLine(integer_array[0]); // Displays the first element of array 
    Console.WriteLine(integer_array[1]); // Displays the Second element of array 
    Console.WriteLine(integer_array[2]); // Displays the third element of array 
    Console.WriteLine(integer_array[3]);
    Console.WriteLine(integer_array[4]);
    Console.WriteLine(integer_array[5]);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit");


}

else if (option == 2)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("                                     ---  Random Number Generator  --- ");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("                                                   Help Menu");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("To navigate through the program type in the number related to the task then press enter.For example To exit the program press 4 and then press enter.");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit");
}
else if (option == 3)
{
    int min, max, howMany;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("                                     ---  Random Number Generator  --- ");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Entre the Minmun Value");
    min =Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Entre the Maximin Value");
    max = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine())+1;
    Console.WriteLine("How many random number you want to generate");
    howMany = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Clear();


    Random rand_number = new Random();  // creates a randon number

    HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();

    while (numbers.Count < howMany)
    {
        int new_number = rand_number.Next(min, max);

        if (!numbers.Contains(new_number))
            numbers.Add(new_number);
    }  // creates howMany (input by user) ramdon numbers between min (input by user) and  max (input by user)and removes duplicates

    int[] integer_array = numbers.ToArray();   // puts number in array 
    Array.Sort(integer_array);  // sorts the array in assending order.


    Console.WriteLine("                                     ---  Random Number Generator  --- ");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();


    for (int i = 0; i < integer_array.length; i++) // this loop gives error length is under lined with red squiggly line 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(integer_array[i]);
    }   // Displays the elements of array 

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit");

}
else if (option == 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit");

}

else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect option slected press any key to Exit");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I Can't explain this question properly. Please ask if any thing is not explained properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would suggest looking up some tutorials on how functions work in C#. Right now your question doesn't fit the Q&A style of SO. Feel free to read up on asking good questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you please provide any resources on function. like a work sheet

Comment: I looked up function all day yesterday and could not find some thing usefull.

Comment: You have an error the Length need to have a capital 'L' in the following line :    for (int i = 0; i < integer_array.Length; i++)

Comment: @ jdweng Thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your for loop at the end (the one which gave you an error). Contains a misspelled property. The

```
integer_array.length
```

should actually be

```
integer_array.Length
```

The 'length' property is 'Length' in C#

And for making sure that your code is looped until any of the correct input keys have been pressed.
You can encapsulate your whole code body with

```
while(true) {
// Your code here
}
```

And then make sure that at the very end; inside each if statement. You should add the keyword

```
break;
```

Except for the last one of course.

And last thing.
For seperating each if statement into their own functions, all you have to do is... (For example)

Change the following code

```
    else if (option == 2)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("                                     ---  Random Number Generator  --- ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("                                                   Help Menu");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("To navigate through the program type in the number related to the task then press enter.For example To exit the program press 4 and then press enter.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit");
    }
```

Into

```
    else if (option == 2)
    {
        OpenHelpMenu();
    }
```

And then at the end of the file; before the last two closing brackets **}**
Add a new function

```
void OpenHelpMenu() {
  Console.Clear();
  Console.WriteLine("                                     ---  Random Number Generator  --- ");
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("                                                   Help Menu");
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("To navigate through the program type in the number related to the task then press enter.For example To exit the program press 4 and then press enter.");
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit");
}
```

Repeat with each if statement and you should be fine :-)